# How to fix Google Play Console warnings about missing content labels

Tags: android, flutter, accessibility

I have a Flutter app targeting Android. I have wrapped most widgets with `Semantics` widget to provide info to screen readers (only excluding Text widgets).

```
 Semantics(
            button: true,
            label: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.description,
            child: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.emoji_events,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                //do something
              },
            ),
          ),
```

However, Google Console as well as the Accessibility Scanner Tool are complaining that content labels are missing for what looks like the entire screen. So there is a red line around the entire screen, not around any of the individual widgets. For some reason there are 723 pictures of my app with the line around it, although my app has only 4 screens!

What am I doing wrong? Does `Scaffold` need to be wrapped with a semantics widget? Or is there a setting missing for `MaterialApp`?